# classification of non-compact Riemannian manifold with Ric>=-(n-1),and first eigenvalue λ=(n-1)^2/4

Tags: dg.differential-geometry

If M is a non-compact Riemannian manifold with Ric>=-(n-1),we know that the first eigenvalue λ(M)<=(n-1)^2/4.What if λ(M)=(n-1)^2/4,then M would be?Are there any paper on this topic?

Comment: There is no such upper bound for the first eigenvalue, a flat torus is a counterexample.

Answer (score 1):

Peter Li and Jiaping Wang have a series of papers on the structure of complete manifolds with
positive spectrum .Peter Li also has a survey article on this topic .You can find it on his home page .